# Are there any risks from cloning a LUKS encrypted partition?

Tags: disk-encryption, luks

I'm using an installation of Ubuntu server  on disk, with some extra packages installed and configuration carried out, on disk as a kind of base image for repeatedly creating other systems. I clone this to a new disk, alter a bit of configuration and have a new working system in very little time. I understand that some sort of automated provisioning system such as Ansible may be a better way to go, but this is my current workflow.

However, I have one partition that's a LUKS container, managed with `cryptsetup`. This only has a single keyslot in use in the LUKS header. My approach is to alter the passphrase interactively with `cryptsetup luksChangeKey`.

I've considered also changing the UUID of the LUKS device. Although I'm not sure if that's adding anything, it will at least differentiate the partitions on different systems.

Am I creating an opportunity for attack by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [cryptsetup wiki](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#6-backup-and-data-recovery),

Note: this section pertains to backups specifically, but I feel like it applies to your situation.

> 6.7 Does a backup compromise security?
>
> Depends on how you do it...There are risks introduced by backups.
>   For example if you change/disable a key-slot in LUKS, a binary backup of the partition
>   will still have the old key-slot. To deal with this, you have to be
>   able to change the key-slot on the backup as well, securely erase the
>   backup or do a filesystem-level backup instead of a binary one.

To clarify, one should ensure that the old key-slot is removed in the cloned partition.

> In both cases, there is an additional (usually small) risk with
>   binary backups: An attacker can see how many sectors and which ones
>   have been changed since the backup.  To prevent this, use a
>   filesystem level backup method that encrypts the whole backup in one
>   go, e.g.  as described above with tar and GnuPG.

To reiterate, one could simply back up the partition by creating an archive and encrypting it, and then moving it to a newly encrypted partition on the new machine and extracting it.

> I've considered also changing the UUID of the LUKS device. Although I'm not sure if that's adding anything, it will at least differentiate the partitions on different systems.

I would recommend this.

> 6.15 Can I clone a LUKS container?
>
> You can, but **IT BREAKS SECURITY**, because the cloned container has the
>   same header and hence the same master key.  You cannot change the
>   master key on a LUKS container, even if you change the passphrase(s),
>   the master key stays the same.  That means whoever has access to one
>   of the clones can decrypt them all, completely bypassing the
>   passphrases.
>
> The right way to do this is to first luksFormat the target container,
>   then to clone the contents of the source container, with both
>   containers mapped, i.e.  decrypted.  You can clone the decrypted
>   contents of a LUKS container in binary mode, although you may run
>   into secondary issues with GUIDs in filesystems, partition tables,
>   RAID-components and the like.  These are just the normal problems
>   binary cloning causes.
>
> Note that if you need to ship (e.g.) cloned LUKS containers with a
>   default passphrase, that is fine as long as each container was
>   individually created (and hence has its own master key).  In this
>   case, changing the default passphrase will make it secure again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd completely forgotten that I could consult the wiki. In fact further down in section 6.15 there's a section saying that cloning breaks security as the master key is never changed. That'd be a useful section to add to your answer.